# In clause with a list of declared variables PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION name_list(name_of_interest text)
RETURNS table (name text,
               sex text,
               age int,
               state text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN query
SELECT name, sex, age, state FROM employee
INNER JOIN address_book ON employee.id = address_book.id
WHERE name = name_of_interest;
```

And then run the function by determining `name_of_interest`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM name_list('Harry Potter');
```

This works fine if only I am interested a single name, but if I want to replace `name_of_interest` to a list of name i.e`('Harry Potter', 'Brad Pitt', 'Stephen Curry')` and changing `WHERE` clause to `WHERE name in (name_of_interest)`, then this function does no longer work.

Any comments or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use array format and send to query:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION name_list(name_of_interest text[])
RETURNS table (name text,
               sex text,
               age int,
               state text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN query
   SELECT name, sex, age, state FROM employee
     INNER JOIN address_book ON employee.id = address_book.id
   WHERE name = any(name_of_interest);
END;
$$;
```

Then run query like below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM name_list(array['Harry Potter', 'Brad Pitt', 'Stephen Curry']::text[]);
```